# How to query a table by different keywords which have to be included

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

- `Object(NUMBER(22,0) id, VARCHAR(300) name)`
- `Keywords(NUMBER(22,0) objectId, VARCHAR(20) keyword)`

Basically when I enter a new `Object` (through a Java program) I compute some keywords and put them into the `Keywords` table, linking them to the relative `Object` by means of the `Keywords.objectId` field.

Now I need to query my `Objects` by some keywords, and each keyword must exist on an item for it to be returned by the query.

An example:

```
Object table
---------------------------------
id          |   name            |
---------------------------------
0           |   hand            |
1           |   foot            |
---------------------------------

Keywords table
---------------------------------
objectId    |   keywords        |
---------------------------------
0           |   finger          |
0           |   ring            |
1           |   finger          |
---------------------------------
```

If I search for the keywords "finger ring" it should return me only "hand", not "foot".

I tried the query

```
SELECT name FROM
Object JOIN Keywords ON Object.id=Keywords.objectId
WHERE
keywords='finger' AND keywords='ring'
```

but obviously it returns me nothing, because the field "keywords" cannot have the value "finger" and "ring" at the same time.

Even this query:

```
SELECT name FROM
Object JOIN Keywords ON Object.id=Keywords.objectId
WHERE
keywords='finger' OR keywords='ring'
```

is wrong, because it returns me both the Objects, because the  "foot" Object has a keyword of "finger" (but not "ring").

What type of query should I write?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`.  Assuming no duplicates:

```
SELECT o.name
FROM Object o JOIN
     Keywords k
     ON o.id = k.objectId
WHERE k.keywords IN ('finger', 'ring')
GROUP BY o.name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```